# compression/packing

Tags: image, compression, packing, quadtree

I have a problem:
Given an array nxm that contains 0's or 1's, I need group the 0 values
into rectangles. At the beginning, I was used a simple quadtree, but
different nodes in the same level of the tree have the same value. I'm
not totally sure if the R-tree works for my problem or another data
structure because I just will use this structure in pre-calculate step
and that's it.

p.s.: I'm working with 2D images

Answer (score 0):

i would opt for a recursive solution. something along the lines of

```
iszeroes returns 1 if matrix has only zeroes
def search_for_zeroes(matrix, colormatrix)
!   conquer - part, matrix is essentially only a cell   
    if size(matrix) .eq. 1 then 
        search_for_zeroes = iszeroes(matrix)
        if iszeroes(colormatrix(matrix)then 
            colormatrix(matrix) = black) 
        end if  
    end if
!   divide - part, looks if four cells are all zero and colors them black
    if search_for_zeroes(upper_left) and search_for_zeroes(upper_right) 
        and search_for_zeroes(lower_left) and search_for_zeroes(lower_right) then
        search_for_zeroes = true
        colormatrix(matrix) = black         
    end if
```

i have not coded it myself, just pseudocode. will change it when i get off work today, but this should work too. 
cheers